# How do these NTP authentication commands differ from one another?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

A [typical Authenticated NTP configuration](http://www.ine.com/resources/ntp-authentication.htm) looks like this:

**NTP Server**

```
R1(config)# ntp master
R1(config)# ntp authentication-key 22 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY
```

**NTP Client:**

```
R2(config)# ntp authenticate
R2(config)# ntp authentication-key 22 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY
R2(config)# ntp trusted-key 22
R2(config)# ntp server 12.0.0.1 key 22
```

I'm confused about the individual purposes of each command in the Client configuration.

What does **`ntp authenticate`** do different from **`ntp trusted-key 22`**? In what cases would I have one command applied but not the other?

I understand **`ntp authenticate`** turns on NTP authentication, and **`ntp authentcation-key ## ...`** configures a specific authentication key. Then **`ntp server x.x.x.x key ##`** associates a particular key to a particular NTP Server. But why would it be necessary to then add an additional command to indicate you trust a particular authentication key (**`ntp trusted-key ...`**)?

Wouldn't simply having the key configured be sufficient to indicate that it is trusted?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

With NTP, authentication is controlled by the requester. An NTP server cannot force authentication on NTP clients; it is happy to send out unauthenticated NTP to clients. A client must request NTP authentication, and it will reject unauthenticated NTP if it has requested authentication.

The `ntp master` command tells a device to be the master clock when an NTP source is not available. This is an oft misunderstood command that is rarely necessary.

The `ntp authentication-key` command merely sets up what the authentication key is. Notice that you set up the key on the server. If that command required authentication, then the NTP server would also require the authentication of its NTP server (NTP is layered).

The `ntp authenticate` command says that the NTP client will require authentication from its NTP server.

The `ntp trusted-key` command tells the client which of the configured keys to use.

The `ntp server` command tells the client which NTP server to use.

---

**Edit based on your comments:**

I originally answered your question:

> What does `ntp authenticate` do different from `ntp trusted-key 22`?
>   In what cases would I have one command applied but not the other?

but that doesn't seem to really be your question.

If you are going to configure multiple NTP servers with different authentication keys, it will probably look something like this:

NTP Server 1:

```
R1(config)#ntp source Loopback1
R1(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY-1
```

NTP Server 2:

```
R2(config)#ntp source Loopback1
R2(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY-2
```

NTP Server 3:

```
R3(config)#ntp source Loopback1
R3(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY-3
```

NTP Client:

```
R4(config)#ntp authenticate
R4(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY-1
R4(config)#ntp authentication-key 2 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY-2
R4(config)#ntp authentication-key 3 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY-3
R4(config)#ntp server 10.11.12.1 key 1
R4(config)#ntp server 10.11.12.2 key 2
R4(config)#ntp server 10.11.12.3 key 3
```

If you are going to configure multiple NTP servers with the same authentication keys, it will probably look something like this:

NTP Server 1:

```
R1(config)#ntp source Loopback1
R1(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY
```

NTP Server 2:

```
R2(config)#ntp source Loopback1
R2(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY
```

NTP Server 3:

```
R3(config)#ntp source Loopback1
R3(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY
```

NTP Client:

```
R4(config)#ntp source Loopback1
R4(config)#ntp authenticate
R4(config)#ntp authentication-key 1 md5 SECRET-NTP-KEY
R4(config)#ntp trusted-key 1
R4(config)#ntp server 10.11.12.1
R4(config)#ntp server 10.11.12.2
R4(config)#ntp server 10.11.12.3
```

Having the NTP source based on the loopback is a good idea. If one link goes down, NTP can still be updated if the traffic can get to and from the server via a different path.

The `ntp trusted-key <key number` command will be used for commands on which you don't use the optional `key <key number>` for any of the `ntp server <server address> or`ntp peer ` commands.

The `ntp source <interface>` command will be used for commands on which you don't use the optional `source <interface>` for any of the `ntp server <server address> or`ntp peer ` commands.

---

**Edit 2:**

The NTP configuration from lab tests (not performed by me, but by a group which tests all network hardware/software features) for routers with IOS 15.x that passed (the password and addresses were changed for protection):

```
ntp authentication-key 1 md5 123456789 7
ntp authenticate
ntp trusted-key 1
ntp source Loopback0
ntp update-calendar
ntp server 10.11.12.13
ntp server 10.12.13.14 prefer
```

Notice that the optional `key <key number>` is not used on the `ntp server <server address>` commands because the servers are configured with the same authentication key.

Comment: Those aren't the commands I am confused about =)

Comment: I appreciate your edit and second attempt, Ron, but I'm afraid you're still not answering my question. You say `ntp trusted-key` tells the client which configured key to use... if so, what does `ntp server x.x.x.x key ##` do?

Comment: That is the key number to use. In your example, you are setting key 22, and you are telling it to use key 22. "_If authentication is enabled, use this command to define one or more key numbers (corresponding to the keys defined with the ntp authentication-key command) that a peer NTP system must provide in its NTP packets, in order for this system to synchronize to it. This function provides protection against accidentally synchronizing the system to a system that is not trusted, because the other system must know the correct authentication key._"

Comment: That is what you said the `ntp trusted-key` command does.

Comment: I think you are missing the part where the key number is optional on the `ntp server <server address>` and `ntp peer <peer address>` commands. You can define a lot of servers and/or peers, and you can use the `ntp trusted-key` to default to using the key for all, or you can use the optional `key <key number>` on the server and peer commands to specify individual or different keys to use for that server or peer. Personally, I wouldn't do it exactly the way you have in the question since I doubt there is an accurate clock attached to the server, and only one key on the client.

Comment: For example, you can use the `ntp source <interface>` command to define the NTP source for the NTP packets, but you can optionally do that on the `ntp server <server address>` and `ntp peer <peer address>` commands, too.

Comment: How sure are you that it works that way, Ron?  Because I finally got some time to lab it out and it isn't working as you describe. I couldn't get a single client to authenticate to a single server without using all three commands (`ntp authentication-key 22 ...` `ntp trusted-key 22` `ntp server 1.1.1.1 key 22`).

Comment: What I wrote is that the `ntp trusted-key <key number>` command is used when you _don't_ use the optional `key <key number>` on the end of the `ntp server <server address>` command, or the `ntp peer <peer address>` command. You do not need both the `ntp trusted-key <key number>` command and the `key <key number>` option at the same time. The `ntp trusted-key <key number>` command basically sets the default key number to use.

Comment: See my edit. It shows that you don't need both at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps there is a difference in IOS versions, but we have it working without both the `ntp trusted-key <key number>` and the optional `key <key number>` on the `ntp server <server address>`. I'm looking at the lab NTP tests from out lab.

Comment: I'll try to lab it out again tomorrow. Ran out of time today.

Comment: @Eddie, see my second edit.

Comment: Saw it. Thanks. Did more testing, and I'm still not seeing it work the way you are describing. Can you get me the output of `show ntp associations detail` on your machines, I'm curious if they are actually showing as authenticated. Can do `show ntp associations detail | i ipv4` to just show the important stuff. Also, what code version are you running? -- my output:  http://pastebin.com/j5f6YrFD